# how to combine two text files using batch script

Tags: string, parsing, command-line

How to remove string and replace with content found in text file using batch script.

**test.txt**

```
Version: 4.5.0
Import:
   //MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt                       #head
   //Packages/Project/config/cde.txt                        #head
View: 24234
  //MPackages/Project/config/ac.txt                     #head
```

Remove any text found between "Import:" and "View:" and replace it with content from sample text file..

**sample.txt**

```
1
2
3
```

**Desired output**

```
Version: 4.5.0
Import:
   1
   2
   3
View: 24234
   //MPackages/Project/config/ac.txt                     #head
```

Comment: The "Desired output" does not have the proper spacing, unless your requirements are more complicated than what you stated.

Comment: proper spacing? just a tab? if tab makes it complicated a space is OK as well :)

Comment: Your output has all lines from test.txt indented an additional 3 spaces, except "Import:" is indented 4 spaces. The sample.txt lines are indented 7 spaces. But based on your description, I would expect all lines to preserve their original alignment. So exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: sorry for confusing you.. i have updated original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with pure batch, but a robust solution is actually quite complicated. I've pretty much quit doing text processing with pure batch.

Instead, I use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression text processor that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The following one liner works fine both from the command line, and within a batch script. It assumes "Import:" and "View:" only appear once.

```
jrepl "^" "   " /f sample.txt | jrepl "^(Import:)[\s\S]*?(^View:)" "$1+'\r\n'+stdin.ReadAll()+$2" /j /m /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

Comment: It worked!!! thank you for your help. if possible can you please explain syntax used for example "[\s\S]*?"